# Why is scope.$watch not triggered when a value is set via $parse assign in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives. One directive show a dropdown and the other directive must hide the dropdown when somewhere else on the page is clicked.

dropdown directive:

```
app.directive('dropdown', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function (newVal, oldVal) {

                obj = angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.dropdown));
                if (newVal) {

                    // hide all drodowns with this attribute                    $(document).find('[dropdown]').each(function (index) {
                    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                        var attrValue = $(this).attr('ng-show');
                        var model = $parse(attrValue);

                        model.assign(scope, false);
                    }
                });
            var offset = obj.offset();
            var new_top = offset.top + 30;
            var right = offset.left + obj.outerWidth() - element.width() + 10;

            element.css('left', right + 'px');
            element.css('top', new_top + 'px'); angular.element(element.children()[0]).css('margin-left', element.width() - 30 + 'px');
            element.show('size', {
                origin: ["top", "right"]
            }, 100);
            }
        });
}
}
});
```

hide dropdown directive:

```
app.directive('hideAllPopups', function ($parse) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $(document).mouseup(function (e) {

                $(document).find('[dropdown]').each(function (index) {

                    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                        var attrValue = $(this).attr('ng-show');
                        var model = $parse(attrValue);

                        model.assign(scope, false);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The latter directive isn't working. What I want to achieve is that when there is click event outside the dropdown, the dropdown must hide.

Showing the dropdown works with this code, but the dropdown never hides anymore and I can't figure out why. So what do I have to do to get my 'hide all dropdowns' get to work?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/ADukg/3063/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$(document).mouseup` callback is an event handler that runs "outside" Angular, so Angular doesn't notice the model change.  Just add `scope.$apply()` and it will work:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        $(document).find('[dropdown]').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                var attrValue = $(this).attr('ng-show');
                var model = $parse(attrValue);
                model.assign(scope, false);
                scope.$apply();  // <<-----------------
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Aargh stupid, I know that I must call `scope.$apply` when not working in the 'Angular-world'.